# Иконка для всплывающей подсказки NotifyIcon

Tags: c#, winforms

Подскажите, как сделать в WinForms свою иконку для NotiFyIcon, когда есть непрочитанный ShowBaloonTip, как по типу пропущенного звонка на значке с телефоном? Или текст рядом с иконкой, который отображается, по типу текста "Телефон".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Перерисовку иконки самого notifyicon'a сделал таким путем:

```
private void DrawTrayString(string str, Font font, Color foreColor, Color backColor)
{
    using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(16, 16))
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    using (Brush brush = new SolidBrush(foreColor))
    {
        g.Clear(backColor);
        g.DrawString(str, font, brush, 0, 0);
        notifyIcon1.Icon = Icon.FromHandle(bmp.GetHicon());
    }
}
```

Вывод:

```
DrawTrayString("+" + rezult.ToString(), new Font("Courier", 8.0f), Color.Red, Color.Transparent);
```

Comment: Как я понял, вы хотите менять иконку на балуне? И чтобы в окне сообщений она же была? Чисто теоретически это возможно, но простого готового решения для WinForms нет. Гуглите _Toast Notification_. Предупреждаю: работы будет непочатый край.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov да либо на балуне, либо динамически менять иконку самого notifyicon'a на текст, который будет меняться в зависимости от задачи. Ну саму иконку я сделал путем прорисовки через Bitmap u Graphics (добавил в главный вопрос), но желательно конечно чтобы отображалось в балуне

Comment: Да, перерисовка иконки сделана правильно. (Я добавил в код освобождение всех ресурсов. Шрифт тоже нужно диспозить.)

Comment: Можете глянуть [здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/send-local-toast-desktop). Но это UWP. Для WinForms готовых решений нет.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov понял спасибо, инфу почитаем)